# Firestore document references, can you expand the document server side?

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, querying

According to this [What is firestore Reference data type good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for). Currently it looks like you have to do a round trip to fetch the data for each document reference in your original query.

Is this on the roadmap to do this expand/aggregation in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, a GraphQL style server-side expansion of references is not possible in Cloud Firestore.

Completely understand the desire, however this is not currently on our roadmap to support.