# How do I restrict writes to a document owned by a user in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I have some articles.

Each article has a **reference field** to the profile **document** of the author who wrote that particular article.

Auth'd users (using Firebase's Auth) will be associated with these profiles.

How do I make these articles editable by the currently logged in user only if that user owns the article?

In Firestore's documentation, there is a recurring example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Allows you to edit the current user document (like a user's profile).
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    // Allows you to read/write messages as long as you're logged in (doesn't matter who you're logged in as, so theoretically you could change other peoples' messages ).
    match /rooms/{roomId} {
      match /messages/{messageId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Where is the example for how to structure and edit a document owned by a certain user?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have a document with e.g. `owner: <uid>` stored in it, you can do:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /somecollection/{id} {
      allow write: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My article document doesn't have `owner: <uid>`, it has `owner: <Reference to another document>` (i.e. `firestore.googleapis.com/project/xxxxxxxxx-eb000/database/(default)/documents/users/ajsidjasidjsaidjasidasj`). The reference _contains_ the uid.

Comment: Fwiw, I was trying exactly what you're proposing, but it doesn't seem to work with References. I suspect I need to do some `get()` stuff, but can't get the syntax just right... :(

Comment: When dealing with user information I'd recommend storing the uid as a string whenever you want to refer to an owner for this exact reason -- there's probably a way to do it otherwise but I'm not as sure how that would work.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Apparently Firestore doesn't offer a way to validate using a Reference type (hopefully they'll add this and I've opened a Feature Request)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for