# Firebase Firestore, get the reference document inside another document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `Firebase Cloud Firestore`, I want when I'm getting a document with reference field inside to receive the reference field as a document and not as a reference to the document...

I have a collection of users and collection of classes (at school) and each class contains a list of references to users (the students in this class).
When I using `document.get()` (to get the class by its reference) it returns an object that contains a list of `DocumentReference` (of the users) so I need to call `document.get()` around 20 more times just to get the users as objects and not as a reference to them.

I want to be able to call `document.get()` once and it will bring me all the references as documents, like that:
[database](https://ibb.co/ee9bew) and [code](https://ibb.co/k0feXG)

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't instruct the Firestore client SDK to automatically follow document references during a fetch of a single document.  You have to request each individual document.  In other words, there is no "join" operation like you might expect in SQL.

See also: [What is firestore Reference data type good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for)

Comment: So I need to request every reference separately? There is no other way to do this?

Comment: That's what my answer is saying.

Comment: Can I use some query function to bring all of those references?

Comment: You can fetch them all individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can get multiple documents from a collection. [Read get mutiple documents section from documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Here's an example

```
db.collection("classes")
    .document(idOfTheClassYouWantToGet)
    .collection("users")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    User user = document.toObject(Users.class);
               }
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: in addOelsenCompleteListener you mean addOnCompleteListener? It will only return a list of document references

Comment: Yes, you can get document by calling task.getResult(). I'll edit my answer

Comment: I think you didn't understand me well, this is my [database now](https://ibb.co/ee9bew) and I want to do something like [this](https://ibb.co/k0feXG) (the code is in kotlin but is the same for java)

Comment: Alright you're keeping paths to users. It isn't a vary good approch. Instead write user to database with add() function. It will create an unique id for each user. Then store that id in the class collection. So you can get users of a class using that.

Comment: @RoiAmiel In case if users have only one class then write users to a sub collection in a class