# How can I populate the reference Field using Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Do you know how I can populate the reference Field on a Document using Firestore?

[image: Firestore]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you create / get a document reference, you can save this into another document.  This example is for the Node SDK, but it should give you an idea of how to implement this for Android.

### Creating a document reference

```
// Create the references
let myFirstDoc = db.collection('myCollection').doc();
let mySecondDoc = db.collection('otherCollection').doc();

let batch = db.batch();

// Save the two documents to the batch
batch.set(myFirstDoc, {someData: true});
batch.set(mySecondDoc, {firstDocRef: myFirstDoc});

// Commit the batch
return batch.commit()
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Data saved');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

### Getting an existing reference

```
return db.collection('myCollection').doc('myDocId')
  .then(documentSnapshot => {
    let newDoc = db.collection('otherCollection').add({otherDoc: documentSnapshot.ref});
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('Data saved');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```