# Use Firebase Functions to create JOINs in Firestore queries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46570119/377011) answer, Firestore references cannot be used for JOIN-like queries, i.e. for retrieving the referencing document and the referenced document in one database round-trip. This can be a performance issue, since network latency costs apply for each database round-trip.

Network latency is only a problem if you are not close to the datacenter, which means that if you do the join server-side, i.e. in the Google datacenter where Firestore runs, then it should not be a problem.

Can we use Firebase Functions to implement this functionality in a generic manner? I'm thinking of a service, implemented in Firebase Functions, which sits between the client and the database. Most queries are just passed to the database (`where`, `orderBy`, `limit` etc. must still be possible), but there should be an additional `populate: true` query parameter. If this parameter is present and set to true, then the referenced documents are returned as well.

Maybe it will also be necessary to indicate *which* documents should be `populate`d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, sounds like you could give it a try.  You can still expect to pay for all documents read by whatever queries you use, even if you don't return that many to the client.

If you really have a lot of joins to perform, it's typically better to pre-compute the joins in another collection, and have the client query that instead.  Then you have the advantage of the client having a local cache the helps both speed and cost.

But there's nothing stopping you from implementing a function that does this, if that's what you need.