# How to model foreign key like relationship in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

Lets imagine I have this data model:

I have a student with name and age, and a student can be in a class and also in a sport team.

In a relational database I would store the students into a `student` column. And in the `class` and `sport` tables I would reference each students via a foreign key.

This has the advantage that when a student celebrates their birth date, I only need to change the `age` in one place, which is the `student` table.

With firestore which I understand to be a nosql, the things I am reading is pointing to a modeling where I have a `class` document, within which all `student` will be embedded. Same also for the `team` document.

The only problem I have with this kind of modeling is if I want to update the age of a student, I would have to update in all the places, the student structure is embedded in.

Is there a better way to achieve what I can have in relational database? Where I have data defined in one place and can be reference in other places, hence giving the benefit of needing to change that data in only one place?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. The `nosql` databases are by design made in a way that you need to store the data in multiple places and `sync` it when required.

What I can recomment is to store as less data as possible to other places. And also try to store more static data like name or birth date that doesn't change so often (but still create a sync for them in any case).

If you don't like to just save the `id` of a student you can save the `reference` to him but in the end it's just the `path` to him. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firebase-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for).