# How to get reference data inside map of parent data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't get this to work.
Code is as follows and problem is res.data() doesn't show in de docs object.

```
getProjects = async () => {
    const colRef = db.collection('parentCollection').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');
    const snapshots = await colRef.get();
    const docs = snapshots.docs.map((doc) => ({
      docId: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
      ...doc
        .data()
        .childId.get()
        .then((res) => res.data()),
    }));
    this.setState({
      list: docs,
    });
  };
```

Comment: What exactly is `childId`?  The value of a `DocumentReference` type field? Or the document ID (i.e. a String) of a child document I guess. But in which (sub) collection?

Comment: `childId` holds reference for a document in another collection.

Comment: Ok, what is the exact type of this field? `Reference` type ?

Comment: thanks for the help posted the answer down below. (yes, it's reference type)

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the comment that the `childId` field is of [type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types) `Reference`.
The following code, using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), should do the trick (untested):

```
const colRef = db.collection('parentCollection').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');
const snapshots = await colRef.get();

const promises = [];
snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
    promises.push(db.doc(snapshot.data().childId).get())
})

const childrenSnapshots = await Promise.all(promises); // Returns an Array of Document Snaphots, in the same order than the parents

const docs = [];
snapshots.forEach((snapshot, index) => {
    docs.push({
        docId: snapshot.id,
        ...snapshot.data(),
        ...childrenSnapshots[index].data()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firebase-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for) worked!

```
db.collection('parentCollection').get()
    .then(res => {
      vm.mainListItems = [];
      res.forEach(doc => {
        let newItem = doc.data();
        newItem.id = doc.id;
        if (newItem. childId) {
          newItem. childId.get()
          .then(res => { 
            newItem.userData = res.data() 
            vm.mainListItems.push(newItem);
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
        } else {
          vm.mainListItems.push(newItem);  
        }

      });
    })
    .catch(err => { console.error(err) });
```