# How to get references data on firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i want to ask something. why when im trying to get the reference firestore data, the value was print out like this. and i dont understand what this values mean, and how to use this.

```
{
  _key: { path: { len: 2, offset: 0, segments: [Array] } },
  converter: null,
  firestore: { app: [FirebaseAppImpl], databaseId: [ie], settings: [Yc] },
  type: "document",
}
```

how to get the reference data and return the proper data from firestore ?

this is what my references looks like:

[image: this is what my references looks like]

Answer (score 0):

When you get the value of a reference field, you get back a [`DocumentReference` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference). If you just want to get its path, like is shown in your console screenshot, you can read the [`path` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreferencepath) of the `DocumentReference`.

---

If you want to get the data from the referenced document (so from the warehouse), you can call `get()` on the `DocumentReference`, same as you'd do for a `DocumentReference` that you'd have constructed in another way. For more examples of that, see the documentation on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: how to get the data from warehouse collection ?

Comment: To read the document at `DocumentReference`, you can `get()` on it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568850/what-is-firebase-firestore-reference-data-type-good-for